# What high level synchronisation construct should be used for thread safe single shot method?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, concurrency

I have a situation where a session of background processing can finish by timing out, user asynchronously cancelling or the session completing. Any of those completion events can run a single shot completion method. The completion method must only be run once. Assume that the session is an instance of an object so any synchronisation must use instance constructs.

Currently I'm using an Atomic Compare and Swap operation on a completion state variable so that each event can test and set the completion state when it runs. The first completion event to fire gets to set the completed state and run the single shot method and the remaining events fail. This works nicely.

However I can't help feeling that I should be able to do this in a higher level way. I tried using a Lock object (NSLock as I'm writing this with Cocoa) but then got a warning that I was releasing a lock that was still in the locked state. This is what I want of course. The lock gets locked once and never unlocked but I was afraid that system resources representing the lock might get leaked.

Anyway, I'm just interested as to whether anyone knows of a more high level way to achieve a single shot method like this.

sample code for any of the completion events:

```
if(OSAtomicCompareAndSwapInt(0, 1, &completed))
{
    self.completionCallback();
}
```

Comment: Having a background process complete more than once sounds like a serious bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a CAS is almost certainly the right thing to do. Locks are not designed for what you need, they are likely to be much more expensive and are semantically a poor match anyway -- the completion is not "locked". It is "done". A boolean flag is the right representation, and doing a CAS ensures that it is manipulated safely in concurrent scenarios. In C++, I'd use `std::atomic_flag` for this, maybe check whether Cocoa has anything similar (this just wraps the CAS in a nicer interface, so that you never accidentally use a non-CAS test on the variable, which would be racy).

(edit: in pthreads, there's a function called `pthread_once` which does what you want, but I wouldn't know about Cocoa; the `pthread_once` interface is quite unwieldy anyway, in my opinion...)

Comment: In C++, I'd use `std::call_once`, not an atomic flag.

Comment: In Grand Central Dispatch there is dispatch_once. I guess I could use that.

Comment: Actually I just checked dispatch_once and that is not a good solution as it needs a static structure to record the completion in.

Comment: @Felix: Is this an instance method, then?

Comment: @PeterHosey Edited original question to clarify.